# How to concatenate arrays with user-defined types in pgsql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-11

### Background

I am using `pgsql` to build database tables, and have historically defined the tables in static arrays (eg `ARRAY[ROW(a,b,...)::user_defined_type,...]`). With the upgrade to PostgreSQL 11.2, I’d like to manipulate dynamic arrays (specifically, to generate new arrays with a number of elements determined at runtime).

### The Problem

When trying to build the arrays, I have tried to use `array_append`, `array_cat`, and `||` (for both array-to-array *and* array-to-element concatenation), as documented in [§9.17](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-array.html). While it works with built-in types, it does not work with the user-defined types (created using `CREATE TYPE`). The error is:

```
No [function | operator] matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

However, since the function definitions of the aforementioned array functions use `anyarray` and `anyelement` as their parameters, I’m not certain why the array functions do not operate on the user-defined types (note that the error does show that an array of user-defined types appears where an `anyarray` parameter expected and the properly- cast user-defined type appears where an `anyelement` should appear).

### Example

DB Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4e52c8c5c7e9f699b01830f5700ad085)

### Other Notes

I have tried to ask the PostgreSQL mail list, but the e-mail server doesn’t seem to like my e-mail address.

### System

PostgreSQL v11.2

Fedora 29

Comment: You will get more help if you edit your question with a minimal example/test case that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ you beat me to it - updated question with fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_append()` works just fine if you use the correct syntax. Your fiddle doesn't work because you used `“` instead of `"` and `‘` instead of `'`. The language for a function is an identifier and shouldn't be quoted to begin with.

String constants need to be enclosed in single quotes, not double quotes. The expression `ROW("a","b")::udt` would result in " column "a" does not exist" because `"a"` is an identifier. You need to use `ROW('a','b')::udt` to initialize a value of type `udt`

So the correct function would be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION abc() RETURNS text AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  x udt;
  y udt[];
BEGIN
  x := ROW('a','b')::udt;
  return array_append(y,x);
END
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
VOLATILE;
```

And `select abc()` returns:

```
abc      
---------
{"(a,b)"}
```

[Working fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=5a0883daf029826f9e505d3adadad7f7)

Comment: Thank you (and apologies for the syntax errors — done out of haste while mobile). The quote syntax around the function language is helpful (assumed the fiddle engine just didn’t support `plpgsql`). While revisiting in light of your answer, I discovered the original error was a blunder in mixing user-defined types. I’ll mark as answer, but will delete the question in a little bit (since a little misleading due to the blunder).

Comment: @Whee that's fine, go ahead and delete it - less noise ;) Not sure what the function was intended for, but this kind of simple "wrapper" functions should be implemented with `language sql` as they have substantially less overhead than PL/pgSQL

Comment: Turns out I can’t delete after all, so my blunder will live on. Note the fiddle was a trivial proof of concept. The real world function is a bit more extensive — great point on using `language sql` (and will likely prompt a review of some legacy PL/pgSQL functions)